# NTP using IPv6 address instead of IPv4

Tags: dns, ipv6, ntp, ipv4

I have a laptop running a version of Linux ( 3.12 ).  I have ntpd installed and configured to sync with time.google.com.  The problem I am having is if I am plugged into a network that only provides an IPV4 address, ntp's dns is using the ipv6 address:

```
    root@Node00b01973d6cc:~# ntpq -pn                                                                                           
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter                                              
==============================================================================                                              
 127.127.1.0     .LOCL.          10 l    7   64    1    0.000    0.000   0.002                                              
 ff0e::101       .MCST.          16 M    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.002                                              
 2001:4860:4806: .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

Now, if I force ntpd to use only IPv4 DNS with the -4 option, everything works fine

```
root@Node00b01973d6cc:~# ntpq -pn 172.16.17.111                                                                             
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter                                              
==============================================================================                                              
 127.127.1.0     .LOCL.          10 l   60   64    1    0.000    0.000   0.002                                              
 216.239.35.12   .GOOG.           1 u   57   64    1   29.278  341.883   0.002
```

But I don't want to do this because if I go to a network that only gives IPv6 addresses this will fail.  Is there a way to configure NTP to only use IPv4 ( or IPv6 ) if my interface actually has an IP address in that family?

The version of ntpd is 4.2.8p12.  This is the ntp.conf file:

```
tinker panic 0                                                              
                                                            
driftfile /usr/local/etc/ntp.drift                                          
disable auth                                                                   
                                                                         
# Update the realtime clock and override its default                         
# stratum of 0.                                                                   
server time.google.com prefer #Real Time Clock                             
server 127.127.1.0 #Real Time Clock                           
server 127.127.1.0 #Real Time Clock                                         
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10                                      
broadcast ff0e::101 iburst ttl 7
```

I have figured out the root cause of why this started to happen.  I recently disabled IPv6 forwarding on my system.  Once I turn IPv6 forwarding back on, NTP starts using the IPv4 address as I would expect.

Why would turning on ipv6 forwarding do this?

By default the system boots with IPv6 forwarding disabled.  To turn it on, in one of the boot scripts I have the line:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

Comment: I don't know. I notice on my Fedora 29 system that `getent hosts time.google.com` returns IPv6 only, even though I do not have ipv6 access, but `getent ahosts time.google.com` returns all results in the correct preference order.  So I tried enabling ipv6 forwarding at runtime, both in `conf.all` and in `conf.wlp2s0`, but it did not change the result of `getent hosts time.google.com`

Comment: To gain a working configuration, I guess you could try an ugly hack with two separate server lines.  `server -4 time.google.com` and `server -6 time.google.com`.

Comment: I had similar problems on Windows using `wget` to download files, but they vanished in the meantime. My guess is that a nameserver when queried via IPv4 should answer with IPv4 addresses first, and when queried via IPv6, it should respond with IPv6 addresses first. In the past `wget` had tried to use IPv6, but could not connect; I had to specify the IPv4 address directly instead of the hostname to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is 2y old, the topic surely is not.

According to [RFC-3484: Default Address Selection for IPv6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3484)
the OS automatically selects the best IP address, which is either IPv6 or IPv4.

If `/etc/gai.conf` is unchanged and your DNS works fine, then Linux (and many other OS) will prefer IPv6 address(es), otherwise it will choose IPv4, to connect to e.g. time.google.com.

You can check that using `getent ahosts time.google.com`.
Every software should try all IP addresses of that list in that order, beginning at the top.

Where did your Linux get the timeservers from? If it is DHCP, then your OS cannot choose, because it got IPv4 IP addresses, not FQDNs. The NTP client may show reverse DNS hosts to IP addresses, not the real configured NTP server "names".

/edit:
I tried with ntpd 4.2.8p15 and ntpd 4.2.6p5 on openSUSE 15.2 and CentOS 7: Both ntpd do not obey RFC 6742 (3484). However chronyd does.

/edit2:
chronyd (3.4) seems to need a looooong time until v4 addresses will be used, if NTP servers are not reachable via IPv6; maybe try yourself.

Comment: Where do you get "every software should try all ip addresses". That behaviour doesn't sound common behaviour .  Usually if one A or AAAA record points to an offline server you will see sporadic connection failures. AFAIK if a client is consistently picking an AAAA record where ipv6 is given it causes failure to connect.

Comment: rfc3484 2.
_Well-behaved applications SHOULD iterate through the list of
   addresses returned from getaddrinfo() until they find a working
   address._

besides that. I see this everyday when a postfix MTA try to send email but fails to connect via v6 .. it will then try v4 and succeeds. this is just one example of many.

Comment: @StefanKarest interesting. So here's the problem with this answer...  The OP has come with a problem where `ntp` is not doing this.  Your answer in response is "well it should", and you offer no information on how to force it to do so.  More over, no standards are being broken as RFC 3484 only says "SHOULD" and not "MUST" (see [rfc 2119](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2119)).  The problem with RFC 3484 is it has placed the responsibility on every application developer and taken it away from the OS developers.  From experience there are a lot of exceptions where this rule is not followed!

Comment: @StefanKarest and now that I re-read it your statement "every software should try all ip addresses" is categorically incorrect because of RFC 2119:  *"This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a particular item"*.  It's incorrect to claim that SHOULD means "all software should" because valid exceptions are explicitly allowed.

Comment: as we do not know wether the ntp client in question uses FQDN or IP Adresses this ^^ discussion is meaningless.
maybe I try with my NTP client (as this only uses a IPv4 address from dhcp).

Comment: We do know this, it's right there at the start of the question:  "I have ntpd installed and configured to sync with time.google.com"

Comment: ok, then we dont know if this ntp client in particular is able to use all IPv6 addresses from DNS. I just wanted to point out every aspect of IPv6 and destination address selection. I see many discussions like: something with IPv6 does not work, how do I disable it?  IMHO this is the wrong approach to IPv6 .. that is why it takes so long to be used and understood, because people first think off disabling it rather than learn how to use it right.
If he is curios, he will find out .. I would use tcpdump. Regards!

Comment: According to the OP it works if he is on a network which is IPv6 enabled, so we know it can use these addresses as long as it has a network to use them over.  The OP is asking to disable IPv6 if their machine is only attached to an IPv4-only network. I'm with you on pushing IPv6 wherever possible, but many networks are still IPv4 only and that is something we all live with (frustraitingly).

Comment: FTR, I tried with ntpd 4.2.8p15 and ntpd 4.2.6p5 on opensuse and centos. both ntpd do not obey rfc6742(3484). chronyd does btw. so someone could fill a bugreport at bugs.ntp.org. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Remove or comment out the IPv6 `localhost` from your hosts file:

```
#::1            localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```